# How to set value for all OneToMany entities?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

I have an `ClientUser` entity with @OneToMany field `customField`:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class ClientUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "client_user_custom_field",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "field_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<ClientFieldValue> customFields;

}
```

And a `ClientFieldValue` entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class ClientFieldValue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    private String value;

}
```

How can I create `ClientFieldValue`'s for all existing `ClientUser`?
I know that I can do smth like:

```
final Iterable<ClientUser> clientUsers = userRepository.findAll();
    clientUsers.forEach(clientUser -> 
                clientUser.setCustomFields(Collections.singleton(new ClientFieldValue())));
    userRepository.saveAll(clientUsers);
```

But I don't want to query all and save them after set.
Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with it? Why don't you want to it? You can write an UPDATE query and update all entities.

Comment: Not really related to your question but why do you use a JoinTable for a OneToMany relation? I would recommend to read this https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/